# How does Restlet handle the HTTP Accept header?

Tags: restlet

The Restlet framework is supposed to handle automatic content negotiation; however, it doesn't seem to do it properly.

When a client sends and HTTP GET request with the Accept header with a value, Restlet doesn't automatically negotiates the content.

Does anyone know how the Accept header is treated?

Answer (score 8):

The Restlet API has extensive support for the "Accept" header. The information is parsed and available via the `Request.getClientInfo().getAcceptedMediaTypes()` : `List<Preference<MediaType>>` method.

Now, in order to automatically negotiate content for you, the Restlet engine needs to have information about the available variants. This is the purpose `org.restlet.resource.Resource class` in Restlet 1.1 and the new `org.restlet.resource.ServerResource` class in the Restlet 2.0 version being developed.

In Restlet 1.1, you create a subclass of Resource, declare variants like this:

```
   getVariants().add(new Variant(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

   getVariants().add(new Variant(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

Then override the `represent(Variant)` method like this:

```
public Representation represent(Variant){

  if(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN.equals(variant.getMediaType()){

     ...

  else if(...)

     ...
}
```

Best regards,
Jerome

PS: please use our mailing list for future questions and look in the archives:
http://www.restlet.org/community/lists

Comment: I will correct a little bit your answer: public Representation represent(Variant variant){ if(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN.isCompatible(variant.getMediaType()){ ... else if(...) ... } So, instead of usin the methos equals(), use the isCompatible()